# OAuthException: A user access token is required to request this resource

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Trying to post to a fan page, I get this:

```
{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"A user access token is required to request this resource."}}
```

while trying to post to [album id]/photos

The weird thing is that I can't find anything on this specific error.

I'll add details if needed.

Comment: give more details.Hope you added access token to the request

Comment: well, I created an app, gave it permissions and requested a token, which I add to the requests (I'm using RestFB)

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121535/an-access-token-is-required-to-request-this-resource-while-accessing-an-album/14127511#14127511

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to post to any of your fan pages, you need to grant manage_pages and publish_stream permissions to your application and then fetch your page access_token to post, here's a link which has examples and explains how to: http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-post-on-facebook-page-as-page-not-as-admin-user-using-php-sdk/31/