# FB.api Response Is Undefined

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a website which integrates with a facebook account to display the notes from the facebook account on the website. However after calling the FB.api method the response I receive is undefined and I am unable to access the data in 'response.data'.

Test

```
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script>

    window.fbAsyncInit =    function() 
                            {

                                FB.init({appId: '12345678', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

                                FB.api  (
                                            '/pagename/notes',  
                                            function(response) 
                                            {

                                                alert(response.data.length);

                                            }

                                        );

                            };

    </script>

</body>
```

Has anyone any idea where I'm going wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [`console.log`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743730/javascript-what-is-console-log-and-how-do-i-use-it) on the response object, you'll realize that it includes an "`error`" property and that `response.error.message` is "*An access token is required to request this resource.*"

You can check if your response includes an error by using the following:

```
function (response) {
    if (response.hasOwnProperty("error")) {
        alert("Error: " + response.error.message);
    } else {
        //Success!
    }
}
```

For the error, a similiar question can be found here: ["An access token is required to request this resource" while accessing an album / photo with Facebook php sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121535/an-access-token-is-required-to-request-this-resource-while-accessing-an-album)

Answer (score 0):

Reading notes requires read_stream permission – your code doesn’t look like you got it first. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/