# Saving the request response url to a text file

Tags: python

I'm new in Python, recently doing a school work request url from Facebook.  Then I have to save the result to a text file.  Here's my code, and I couldn't figure out how to save the response result.  Can anyone help or point a hint?  Very much appreciated.

```
import requests

url = "http://graph.facebook.com/{}/picture?type=large"
default = "https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yl/r/HsTZSDw4avx.gif"

for user_id in range(4, 10):
response = requests.get(url.format(str(user_id)))
if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    if response.url != default:
        print(response.url)

f = open("Output.txt", "w+", encoding = "UTF-8")
f.write(response.text)
f.close()
```

Comment: What is your result, error and expected result?

Comment: your indentations seem off

Comment: the txt file I saved only showed "http://graph.facebook.com/{}/picture?type=large" or some error message, but not the url.

Comment: My output: 
```
{"error":{"message":"An access token is required to request this resource.","type":"OAuthException","code":104,"fbtrace_id":"AWIyiD4GixOdqxgvtU5cY-Q"}}
```
Requires an access token. You should probably use some other website other than FB if that's a choice.

Comment: @ask_me, yes, you r right, that's another outcome I had.  Unfortunately, like I said, it's a school work, I have to request those urls form FB.  I just can't seem to figure out how to save it into a txt file.

Comment: See this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121535/an-access-token-is-required-to-request-this-resource-while-accessing-an-album

Check the second answer. What you need is an access token. read up about what access tokens are if you don't know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["An access token is required to request this resource" while accessing an album / photo with Facebook php sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121535/an-access-token-is-required-to-request-this-resource-while-accessing-an-album)

Comment: For future reference, googling the error message often leads to solutions to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you're having with saving the response is that you're overwriting it each time. You want to either open your output in 'append' mode

```
    with open("Output.txt", "a", encoding = "UTF-8") as f:
        f.write(response.url)
```

Or, construct the desired output and write once:

```
output = []
for user_id in range(4, 10):
    response = requests.get(url.format(str(user_id)))
    if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        if response.url != default:
            print(response.url)
            output.append(response.url)

with open("Output.txt", "w", encoding = "UTF-8") as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(output))
```

That being said... I don't think your response is text.
Try running the following!

```
import requests

url = "http://graph.facebook.com/{}/picture?type=large"
default = "https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yl/r/HsTZSDw4avx.gif"

output = []
for user_id in range(4, 10):
    response = requests.get(url.format(str(user_id)))
    if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        if response.url != default:
            print(response.url)
            output.append(response.content)

for i, data in enumerate(output):
    with open(f"Output{i}.gif", "wb") as f:
        f.write(data)
```

One of my output looks like:

[image: fb_default_img]

Jupyter Screenshot:

[image: Jupyter Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you very much, but the output still not the way I need.  I'll keep trying to figure it out, very appreciated.

Comment: I just made an edit, check it out :)

Comment: Yep, the response, when successful, is a gif image. You can see my example output where I tell it to display the response as an image.

Comment: The display content is correct, it's those 4 urls I have to save it to a text file.  That's where I got stuck.

Comment: Okay, if it's the URLs you want, look back to my original response, and instead of `response.text` just do `response.url`~

Comment: And next time instead of "save the result", specify "save the urls with successful status codes", and you'll get an answer much faster :')

Comment: Yeah, I tried that before.  The output will only show "http://graph.facebook.com/9/picture?type=large" in the txt file.

Comment: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEkTu.png) Try again.

Comment: OMG!  That's the output I was trying to have, thank you so much for the help!  :)